# Run Javascript when I open any website page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to modify css of a page using a javascript code.
My aim is to run this javascript automatically whenever I open a website in Chrome.
I have tried several Chrome extensions but it seems that it doesn't do the job (Requestly, Violentmonkey, Tampermonkey).

Do you have any work around ?

Here is my use case:
I use a web app to fulfill orders. In my order page, I have several products and quantity of each product (see screenshot). I want to change the css to make the text bigger and red when the quantity is 2 (and not 1). So I am sure I don't miss anything.
I cannot change anything on the web app because it is a third-party app.

Here is my javascript function, it works well when I manually apply the script but I can't find a way to do it automatically:

```
function Change(word) {

  //find all html elements on the page inside the body tag
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll("td");
  // get our replacement ready
  let span = "<span style='color:blue;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;'>" + word + "</span>";
  //loop through all the elements
  for (let x = 0; x < elems.length; x++) {
    // for each element, 'split' by the word we're looking for, then 'join' it back with the replacement

// put your script function here

    elems[x].innerHTML = elems[x].innerHTML.split(word).join(span);
  }
}

Change('2');
```

Comment: FYI changing innerHTML can lead to bigger issues if they bound events to anything in that element.

Comment: Perhaps consider [user stylesheets](https://superuser.com/questions/560539/how-can-i-force-my-css-styles-when-i-visit-a-website).

Comment: @jarmod would be hard to match a style to a number range

Comment: Are you sure the reason why it fails with Tamper Monkey and such is because the data is being loaded dynamically? In the console you are running after the elements are there. My guess is you need to adjust the script to wait until the content is loaded.

Comment: @epascarello yes, good point in this specific case. Hopefully generally useful though for custom CSS overrides.